# SPARQL DBpedia - Retrieve category information in any language by using labels

Tags: resources, label, sparql, categories, dbpedia

I have a problem, which I explain on following example:

I want to retrieve all information **in any language** on a category. I **must** use `?category` as a **label** and the **language labels** `en`, as they are inputs in my program.

The query looks like this, but when I change the language I don't receive any information on the category. I know the problem lies in the dcterms:subject, because `?category` returns `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Countries_in_Europe` (see first example below).

For example to search for a category label in german you have to use `http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Kategorie:Staat_in_Europa` (see second example below).

```
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?objectLabel WHERE {
       ?subject dcterms:subject ?category ; rdfs:label ?objectLabel 
       ?category rdfs:label "Countries in Europe"@en .
FILTER (LANG(?objectLabel)='en')
}
```

Equivalent query in different language that doesn't work as example:

```
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?objectLabel WHERE {
       ?subject dcterms:subject ?category ; rdfs:label ?objectLabel 
       ?category rdfs:label "Staat in Europa"@de .
FILTER (LANG(?objectLabel)='de')
}
```

Is there a similar or different way / method to solve the problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't you have to use the German DBpedia then? Since you're referring to data that is extracted from German Wikipedia.

Comment: Seems to be a solution, but a complicated one. I could probably use always english labels, but change the language labels to the desired language...which would be a bit easier for me. Your help is appreciated though.

Comment: Well the problem is that the DBpedia endpoint doesn't contain the Gerrnan labels for the categories. I don't see any other workaround besides using the German endpoint then. Either in a separate query or via the SPARQL 1.1 federated query support using the `SERVICE` keyword.

Comment: @AKSW How would the federated query look like in my example?

Comment: I would not use a federated query here as long as you only use data from one dataset. In your case it's more efficient to use the German DBpedia dataset.

Comment: I agree on your statement. Categories are working now for all languages using the required language dataset. Thank you.